# Global Variables Web Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, static, webforms

When using web methods in WebForms, these methods must be declared as static (or shared in VB) in their respective page code behind. Some times I need  global variables that need to be used by multiple web methods and in order to be used, these must be declared as static as well.

I'm facing 2 problems right now. When multiple users use these variables when invoking web methods in the same page, because they're static if they're asigned while many users are interacting, the last value of these variables are now for every user, not only the one who assigned them. I thought of making them static but at the same time SET and GET them as a property with a session key, but there comes the other problem, if a user request the same page for example in multiple tabs, variables now have the risk to be changed in each page request.

My question is, How can I have variables that can be used by web methods that are unique to every user and at the same time for every user resquest?

Comment: Session object. Cache. - that if you want each user have its own variable. If they share one - just use `synclock`

Comment: if you don't want it shared across multiple tabs, could you just generate a guid or some random string on page load, store it on the client and pass it up with every web method call to use as the key? Having said that, I agree with the answer from Alexei that it would be better to be stateless. What happens when someone closes their browser? data stays in server memory until the next time the app pool recycles?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is better to have stateless service and pass all necessary information as parameter of the call.

If you can't do that - session state is the right user-level storage. Note that when using SQL session state its locking policy designed for pages rather than multiple, potentially parallel method calls - that could add significant delays then have multiple calls from same user.